# For loop not work in excel worksheet_python

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, loops, for-loop

Now I'm use for loop for detect empty cell in excel file.I need stop loop when it find blank cell.But my loop not stop working.**I need to break loop when it find blank cell.**

This's my code:

```
for i in excel:
if i == None:
    print('Finish work')
    break
elif i == '1':
    py.hotkey('Enter')
else:
    py.hotkey('Enter','Tab')
    py.hotkey('tab');py.hotkey('tab');py.hotkey('tab');py.hotkey('tab');py.hotkey('tab');py.hotkey('tab')
```

This's my excel File Image:
[This's my excel File picture i don't have reputation score i can't post picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOTFw.png)

Comment: Are you trying to loop for each row in the spreadsheet, then stop when no more rows have data?

Comment: Yes.My loop not stop when it find blank cell.(Or cell = B4)

Comment: Are you using py.hotkey to go to new cells in the spreadsheet?

Comment: Yes.I'm using py.hotkey to go to new cells in the spreadsheet

Answer (score 0):

You can do this pretty easy with pylightxl. If all you are doing is reading data (see docs: https://pylightxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html)

```
import pylightxl as xl

db = pylightxl.readxl('yourExcelFile.xlsx')

# assuming your data is in Sheet1 and column A (you can change this to whatever you need)
for celldata in db.xl('Sheet1').col(1):
    if celldata == '':
        print('Finish work')
        break
    elif celldata == '1':
        # do something
        pass
    else:
        # do something else
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Judging off comments and further understanding it seems you would like to somehow utilize this information within Python.

Using py.hotkey to skip lines, tab through cells etc searching for blanks is not recommended.

You could easily import the xlsx/csv into Python and iterate over it using lists/pandas etc. Here is an example of how to import an xlsx into Python, and iterate over the data using Pandas.

```
# Import Pandas
import pandas as pd

# Create dataframe referencing Excel file

df = pd.read_excel("spreadsheet.xlsx")

# This is what the dataframe looks like

df

Unnamed: 0 Supplier Name Payment Date  ...  Satang break   Description
0          17          Mr.A      #######  ...       0     1  Cash advance
1          21          Mr.B      #######  ...       0     1  Cash advance

[2 rows x 9 columns]

# Iterate over all rows in the dataframe

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print(row['Supplier Name'], row['Payment Date'])

# Printed result based on row['column name']
Mr.A #######
Mr.B #######
```

There are other methods to import and parse spreadsheets, however give Pandas a go! It's a very powerful module and should be able to help you along you way with this project.